# Could not locate package gthread-2.0

Tags: ubuntu, camera, glib, genicam, aravis

I am trying to install the aravis project version 0.6, to display video signal through an ethernet camera whose model is HT-GE502C-T, this is compatible with genicam and gige vision protocols. For this I am using ubuntu 22.04, the problem is that when installing the dependencies of the project does not find the dependency gthread-2.0.

```
sudo apt install gthread-2.0

Reading the package list... Done

Creating dependency tree... Done

Reading status information... Done

E: Could not locate package gthread-2.0

E: No package could be found using "*" with "gthread-2.0".
```

I have been looking at the different solutions and have tried the following commands:

`sudo apt install libgtk2.0-dev` 
This command was not useful for me because the dependency was already installed on the system.

`sudo apt-get install build-essential zlib1g-dev pkg-config libglib2.0-dev binutils-dev libboost-all-dev autoconf libtool libssl-dev libpixman-1-dev` 
and with this command I have not been able to install the gthread-2.0 dependency either.

Is there any way to install the gthread-2.0 dependency?

I have also tried to install a higher version of aravis but apparently from version 0.7 onwards the configure.ac file where the necessary dependencies are shown is not shown and versions lower than 0.7 include the file but gthread-2.0 is required. Is this dependency needed in versions 0.7 and 0.8? Where I could see the necessary libraries of these last two versions?

Comment: If you have `libglib2.0-dev` then you almost certainly have the dependency installed. It seems more likely that there's a misconfiguration and pkg-config can't find it.